# Using Join with List and Data Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am new to working with LINQ and I would like to know, what's the better approach to achieve my requirement.

**Requirement Details:**
CSV = "test1, test2, test3"

CSV can have more than 100 comma-separated values

For each value in comma-separated values, I need to get data from DB using LINQ something like below.
DBContext.Where(t => t.Column1 == test1)

Can anyone help me, what's the better approach to do the same in entity framework?

I think, looping through Array by splitting CSV won't be optimal, if CSV has more values.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will translate to a SQL "in", and will likely be more efficient than looping and doing a query for each item.

`SELECT * FROM MyTable where Column1 IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')`

```
// Read CSV to array
var csv = new [] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};

// Get values from database 
DBContext.Where(t => csv.Contains(t.Column1));
```

Comment: Is there a way to select only one row like FirstOrDefault() (TOP 1 in SQL) for each value in CSV

Comment: For that you would want to use group by and min/max or pull all the data and filter in memory